# Is there an algorithm to get all minimal paths between all nodes in a weight graph but with updates in edges?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I would like to know if exists an algorithm capable to get all minimal paths in a weight graph, I know it is possible to use Bellman-Ford for getting all minimal paths, but my problems is that I have queries in the edges, each time a particular edge's weight changes.

I know a lot of algorithms capable to get certain values with queries, like Segment Tree or Sparse Table.

Comment: Have you looked at Prim's, Kruskal's and DIjkstra's algorithms?

Comment: I think your description is too abstract... do you have an example of what you're trying to solve? All minimal paths from a single node or from all nodes?

Comment: Ok, my problem is about getting all minimal paths between one node to all nodes. Of course, this is a weight graph, so a good implementation it would be a Dijkstra Algorithm or using a Bellman-Ford. This is a good answer, since I have all results in an array. The bad here is that it exists queries to update some edges in their weights. Then, I'll need to apply again my algorithm, either Dijkstra or Bellman-Ford. But, is there a way to get all minimal paths between ALL nodes with queries in the weigth of the edges in certain times? Because I don't know some algorithm that does it

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/retrieving-the-shortest-path-of-a-dynamic-graph does this thread help?

Comment: Yes ash, thanks a lot!